# SLN Configuration File : mapping issues

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, sln-file

I want to customise the sln file of my solution to manage:

- 3 projects
- 5 configurations: Debug, Production_total, Production_Partial, Release and Recette

Each configuration should use "Any CPU" platform.

I came to this:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.3.32922.545
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{778DAE3C-4631-46EA-AA77-85C1314464D9}") = "Dumbow2", "Dumbow 2\Dumbow2.vbproj", "{101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3} = {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{778DAE3C-4631-46EA-AA77-85C1314464D9}") = "Dumbow2_update_version_reference", "Dumbow2_update_version_reference\Dumbow2_update_version_reference.vbproj", "{9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133} = {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{778DAE3C-4631-46EA-AA77-85C1314464D9}") = "Dumbow2_prebuilt", "Dumbow2_prebuilt\Dumbow2_prebuilt.vbproj", "{0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU       
        Production_Partial|Any CPU = Production_Partial|Any CPU
        Production_Total|Any CPU = Production_Total|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU       
        Recette|Any CPU = Recette|Any CPU       
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Production_Total|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Production_Total|x64
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Production_Total|Any CPU.Build.0 = Production_Total|x64
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Production_Partial|x64
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.Build.0 = Production_Partial|x64
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Recette|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Recette|x64
        {101E24DB-EFB4-4375-A206-AC3FD4518FE7}.Recette|Any CPU.Build.0 = Recette|x64
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Production_Total|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Production_Total|x64
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Production_Total|Any CPU.Build.0 = Production_Total|x64
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Production_Partial|x64
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.Build.0 = Production_Partial|x64
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Recette|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Recette|x64      
        {9DD6A3BA-4177-477A-A4BF-DEC95B7984C3}.Recette|Any CPU.Build.0 = Recette|x64        
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Production_Total|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Production_Total|x64
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Production_Total|Any CPU.Build.0 = Production_Total|x64
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Production_Partial|x64
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.Build.0 = Production_Partial|x64
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Recette|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Recette|x64
        {0B3CCBC2-9BE8-4B03-9D91-86ED2474F133}.Recette|Any CPU.Build.0 = Recette|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {D8CF22E9-68E7-417A-8707-BAF2C4AC2391}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

The solution loads in Visual Studio but I got "Current solution contains incorrect configuration mappings".
Did the issue come from that "customised" SLN File or did it come from the fact there is some mismatches between the SLN files and the vbproj files of each project within the solution?

Last question: in Visual Studio UI, only two configuration display. I don't get why.
[image]

Comment: Don't edit the SLN file by hand. Use Visual Studio to add the projects and add the configurations.

Comment: Ok, thanks @JonathanDodds i did it and it works but i didn't get why there is some documentation about the content of sln files if user shouldn't edit it.

Comment: Are you referring to this - [Solution (.sln) file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-dot-sln-file?view=vs-2022)? That document is really about VSPackages and is not a complete description of the sln file. Did you find other documentation somewhwerer else?

Comment: I was referring to the link you mentioned.

Comment: @Boris Hi, you can take a look at my answer. Your situation can be fixed, but as jonathan said, I also don't recommend you to write sln file manually, this is meanless(Because VS doesn't only consider this file you write, the file will be regenerate after solution loaded.), And it will destroy the internal consistency of VS. Manually writing sln will cause you to encounter many problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your situation:

[image]

There is a problem with your .sln file.

`GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms)` section shows configuration mappings to `x64`, while you intended to use `Any CPU`.

On my side it is:

[image]

Once I change to this:

[image]

The issue will disappear:

[image]

If you manually write the sln like original(map to x64), you should be able to reproduce the issue again.

As Jonathan said, please don't try to write the sln file manually, otherwise, there may be some unexpected errors.

> in Visual Studio UI, only two configuration display. I don't get why.

You need to reopen the vs after changing manually and to tell the truth, the vs doesn't only consider your writing, it also considers the caches in other places, it will reformat after reload. I suggest you not write it, otherwise, it will make something unexpected.

But I can also reproduce this situation.

This is my sln file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.5.33530.505
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "ConsoleApp7", "ConsoleApp7.csproj", "{D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}"
EndProject
Project("{778DAE3C-4631-46EA-AA77-85C1314464D9}") = "ConsoleApp8", "..\ConsoleApp8\ConsoleApp8.vbproj", "{AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU       
        Production_Partial|Any CPU = Production_Partial|Any CPU
        Production_Total|Any CPU = Production_Total|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU       
        Recette|Any CPU = Recette|Any CPU       
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test4|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test4|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test5|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test5|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = test2|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = test2|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Production_Partial|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.test|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = test|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.test|Any CPU.Build.0 = test|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {4A4DFA2A-F099-4DDC-86E1-343A4B11F86A}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

And the active configuration is not loaded:

[image]

If you really want to write and make it work, please don't copy&paste(it may contains unexpected bytes), write it manually one by one, it works on my side:

For example, I write the section 'Recette' like this:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.5.33530.505
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "ConsoleApp7", "ConsoleApp7.csproj", "{D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}"
EndProject
Project("{778DAE3C-4631-46EA-AA77-85C1314464D9}") = "ConsoleApp8", "..\ConsoleApp8\ConsoleApp8.vbproj", "{AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Production_Partial|Any CPU = Production_Partial|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        test|Any CPU = test|Any CPU
        Recette|Any CPU = Recette|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test4|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test4|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test5|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5EBDFAE-03A5-466C-9DE1-907AEDAE83CF}.test5|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = test2|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = test2|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Production_Partial|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Production_Partial|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.test|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = test|Any CPU
        {AAC48834-364F-4CD9-81F8-34D5264A1A05}.test|Any CPU.Build.0 = test|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {4A4DFA2A-F099-4DDC-86E1-343A4B11F86A}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

And it works:

[image]

Remember to write one by one, otherwise the changes will be droped by VS immediately(I suspect you add them all in one time.).

**Anyway, I strongly do not recommend that you write by hand.** This may cause a lot of problems. Although you can handwrite some of the things you encounter now, please only take it as a try(to better understand it). Please remember that VS not only refers to your manually written sln file, but also Lots of other binaries, caches and stuff like that.