# How to successfully build a Microsoft.Dotnet.Wpf.sln repository downloaded from GitHub at your home PC?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, nuget-package-restore, buildconfiguration

I am trying to build a `Microsoft.Dotnet.Wpf.sln` which I downloaded from GitHub [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf). I installed `Visual Studio 2022 Preview` as mentioned in the instruction. Now when I open the Microsoft.Dotnet.Wpf.sln in VS2022 I get warning

> Current solution contains incorrect configurations mappings. It may
> cause projects to not work correctly

I tried to `Restore nuget package` for solution, still I can see unresolved dependencies.
[image]

The Nuget package source are

[image]

Is there any guidance and steps to follow to successfully build this repo?

Comment: What is the nuget source you are currently using?

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu-MSFT, Thanks for your message. I have updated my question with Nuget Source Information

Comment: Hi, you could take a look of my answer, it should works for your situation, the issue should comes from the sln file. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce your situation:

[image]

You can take a look at another answer of mine about why this happens:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77514819/6261890

And for your situation, you can use a simple method to avoid this:

Close your visual studio, open the Microsoft.Dotnet.Wpf.sln file via text editor, and remove everything between `GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution` and `EndGlobalSection`.

Make it like this:

[image]

Save it, and then open it via visual studio.

After that, the issue you encountered should disappear.

By the way, I checked the info of the projects, it related to .net sdk 9.0. So please also use the latest visual studio version which support the .net sdk 9.0.

And to avoid other problems, I suggest you using official NuGet source:

`https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: Hi Bowman, thanks for your reply, I followed your steps, which removed OpenConfiguration Error, but still too many errors, Is the solution compiling for you?. Please can you share your changes on a git repository?